# Why is paintComponent not drawing on the panel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am having some trouble getting my code to draw to my jpanel.

Everything runs correctly except the graphics drawing.

There are other answers saying that I need to set the size of the panel with setSize, but I already do that.

Other answers say that I need to call `super.paintComponent(g);`, but I do that as well.

What am I missing?

Here is my code:

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import static java.awt.Color.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    //Declare all class vars.
    private Snake snake = new Snake(50,50,50);

    //Declare all Player global booleans
    private boolean leftPressed, rightPressed, upPressed, downPressed;

    //Declare all Gamestate gobal booleans
//    private boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Main main = new Main();

        main.createFrame();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main::customUpdate);
    }



    private void createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snaek");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(800,800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.requestFocus();
        panel.addKeyListener(this);
        panel.setSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()));
        Frame.getFrames();
    }

    private void customUpdate() {
        if(leftPressed) {
            snake.changeX(-1);
        } else if(upPressed) {
            snake.changeY(-1);
        } else if(downPressed) {
            snake.changeY(1);
        } else if(rightPressed) {
            snake.changeX(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(black);
        g.drawRect(snake.getX(), snake.getY(), snake.getSize(), snake.getSize());
        g.drawRect(100,100,200,200);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case 37:
//                System.out.println("Left?");
                leftPressed = true;
                break;
            case 38:
//                System.out.println("Up?");
                upPressed = true;
                break;
            case 39:
//                System.out.println("Right?");
                rightPressed = true;
                break;
            case 40:
                System.out.println("Down?");
                downPressed = true;
                break;
            case 27: //Escape
                System.out.println(snake.getX());
                break;
            case 50: //Space
//                spacePressed = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case 37:
//                System.out.println("Left?");
                leftPressed = false;
                break;
            case 38:
//                System.out.println("Up?");
                upPressed = false;
                break;
            case 39:
//                System.out.println("Right?");
                rightPressed = false;
                break;
            case 40:
//                System.out.println("Down?");
                downPressed = false;
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `repaint` inside `paintComponent`. Instead, repaint when you require it (after changing positions). But you can't, cause you only call `customUpdate` once. May want to use a `Timer` or switch to active rendering.

Comment: `There are other answers saying that I need to set the size of the panel with setSize` - I have never seen an answer like that. You should NOT be setting the size of any component. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size and location of a component. What you should be doing is overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method of your panel to return the preferred size. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a new `JPanel` here:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

And then adding it to the `JFrame`

```
frame.add(panel);
```

Instead you should add your panel (`Main`) into it

```
frame.add(this);
```

Also, as stated by @VinceEmigh in the comments above, avoid calling `repaint()` in the `paintComponent()` method, otherwise you could fall into an endless loop, lagging or freezing in your app. Painting methods are for painting only.

Another tip, is to use `KeyBindings` instead of `KeyListener` or you could fall into your program not responding to the key events...

And I would also move `frame.setVisible(true);` line to the end of `createFrame()` method...

Comment: This fixed it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, please be sure to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it :)

Comment: Why should I add `frame.setVisible` at the end instead of the beggining?  Does it affect performance at all or is it just good practice?

Comment: I'll be sure to accept this answer, I just need to wait until stack overflow lets me :)

Comment: It is a good practice, and it doesn't improve performance but you might get a "blank" screen randomly if you don't, always call that method after you've added all your components to the frame, then and only then call `setVisible(...)` on it.

Comment: @wanderer0810 Layouts. When using a layout, the root container must be informed when a new component has been added or an existing component has changed location/size. You inform the root container by calling `revalidate()` on it, but it's only needed if the root container is already being displayed, which is why it's preferred to `setVisible` last

Answer (score 4):

You are adding a default panel to your JFrame.  You want to add your custom JPanel instead.